# Сумма двузначных чисел тоже двузначное чтсло

Tags: тестирование, калькулятор, задание-на-собеседовании

Хочется услышать ещё мнений по задачке: написать тест на простейшую программу - сумма сложения двузначных чисел тоже двузначное число.

Вот такая какая-то непонятная формулировка, мне кажется не хватает какой-то конкретики. Но допустим это вот программка из школьного курса первых уроков информатики по Паскалю.

Я рассуждаю как: определяю диапазон корректных значений - двузначные числа, то есть 10-99. При этом сложение некоторых уже не будет двузначным числом, то есть проверяем например 1)*10+55* и получаем *65*, что ок и 2)*10+99* и получаем *115*, что не ок.

Но есть ли жесткое ограничение на ввод числа для сложения непрнятно, можно же ввести одно-, трех- и так далее значное число. С однозначными числами: 3)*0+5=5* сумма однозначных - однозначное и 4)*8+9=17* сумма однозначных - двузначное. Правда складывая трех- и более значные числа двузначное мы не получим, если только не использовать отрицательные числа 5)*312+(-300)=12*.
А если просто пустое поле оставить, то вообще не посчитается ничего или ошибка вылезет, типа введите данные 6) *пустое поле*

Как-то так. Путаные рассуждения, но хочется разобрааться

Comment: Ну если надо написать тест, то видимо на вход я могу дать что-угодно, даже не число. Надо и такие случаи мониторить

Comment: Задание однозначно говорит, что проверяться должна "сумма сложения **двузначных** чисел". Соответственно если введено не двузначное число (трёхзначное, отрицательное, дробное, не-число) - это нужно выявить и сообщить об ошибке входных данных.

Comment: И ещё я бы уточнил - ввод, например, `05`, является а) однозначным числом б) двузначным числом в) недопустимым операндом.

Comment: 90 + (-30) = 60 таким образом -30 - это двузначное число или таки недопустимое число? ибо если -30 двузначное число, то и (-90) + 60 = -30 является верным решением.